# Erro no console do chrome

Tags: navegador-de-internet, console

No console no navegador chrome, estou com estes erros: Tenho que preocupar. Somente no Chrome

```
content-script.js:12 Unhandled rejection Error
    at child.onBeforeRender (chrome-extension://cpaibbcbodhimfnjnakiidgbpiehfgci/scripts/frames.js:4:18911)
    at Object._triggerMethod (chrome-extension://cpaibbcbodhimfnjnakiidgbpiehfgci/scripts/frames.js:7:15234)
    at child.triggerMethod (chrome-extension://cpaibbcbodhimfnjnakiidgbpiehfgci/scripts/frames.js:8:1287)
    at child.render (chrome-extension://cpaibbcbodhimfnjnakiidgbpiehfgci/scripts/frames.js:8:3436)
    at child.render (chrome-extension://cpaibbcbodhimfnjnakiidgbpiehfgci/scripts/frames.js:1:695)
    at child.render (chrome-extension://cpaibbcbodhimfnjnakiidgbpiehfgci/scripts/frames.js:8:18302)
    at child.render (chrome-extension://cpaibbcbodhimfnjnakiidgbpiehfgci/scripts/frames.js:1:695)
    at onDocumentLoaded (chrome-extension://cpaibbcbodhimfnjnakiidgbpiehfgci/scripts/content-script.js:7:26954)
From previous event:
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (chrome-extension://cpaibbcbodhimfnjnakiidgbpiehfgci/scripts/content-script.js:7:27598)
    at fire (chrome-extension://cpaibbcbodhimfnjnakiidgbpiehfgci/scripts/content-script-libs.js:2:28013)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (chrome-extension://cpaibbcbodhimfnjnakiidgbpiehfgci/scripts/content-script-libs.js:2:29202)
    at Function.ready (chrome-extension://cpaibbcbodhimfnjnakiidgbpiehfgci/scripts/content-script-libs.js:3:64)
    at HTMLDocument.completed (chrome-extension://cpaibbcbodhimfnjnakiidgbpiehfgci/scripts/content-script-libs.js:1:2164)
```

Comment: Você está desenvolvendo uma extensão no chrome? Caso não, está dando conflito com alguma extensão instalada ai

Comment: Entendi. Tenho algumas instalada. Mas deve ser no meu PC. valeu